# Не могу использовать методы из зависимостей указных в pom.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, test-automation, appium

---

Начал писать проекты по автоматизации проектов используя maven. IDE: Idea.
Создал проект на основе maven в pom указал зависимости:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 //часть кода удалена в целях оптимизации занимаемого пространства.
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Далее был создан package appiumSetting в src>test>java и создан класс samsung в нем пытаюсь выполнить импорт методов из io.appium, но idea предлагает оптимизировать импорт и не дает использовать зависимости.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить

Comment: Уберите < scope> test ваших зависимостей

Comment: Убрал, сработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите  test ваших зависимостей и всё будет хорошо.

Уберите.

```
  <scope>test</scope>
```